# How to parse an array of JSON from database in swift

Tags: json, swift

In my app I'm trying to parse a JSON file.

This is my JSON:

> [ { "locals": [{"name": "Mission Chinese Food", "localDescription": "A", "photograph": "img_02.jpg", "address": "171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002", "timetable": "Lunedi al Sabato 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00 Domenica 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00", "numberOfReviews": 10, "numberInCity": 2, "cityName": "New York", "ratingValue": 5 }, { "locals": [{"name": "Mission Chinese Food", "localDescription": "A", "photograph": "img_02.jpg", "address": "171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002", "timetable": "Lunedi al Sabato 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00 Domenica 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00", "numberOfReviews": 10, "numberInCity": 2, "cityName": "New York", "ratingValue": 5 }, ]

This is my swift file:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.litos.srl/showtime/dbGetLocal.php")

do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
    print(data[0])

    guard let rootObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String:AnyObject]]  else {
    return locals
}

print(rootObject)
let localsObjects = rootObject[0]["locals"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]

    } catch {
        print(error)
        return locals
    }
    return locals
}
```

This is the error that occurs in Xcode when I build and run the code:

> 60
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
>   2018-06-29 09:44:19.293880+0200 eventsProject[13504:4365358] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
>   2018-06-29 09:44:19.294067+0200 eventsProject[13504:4365358] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert
>   2018-06-29 09:44:19.294258+0200 eventsProject[13504:4365358] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2871 [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN(6): operation failed because the connection was cleanly shut down with a close_notify alert

How can I parse my JSON and get data on swift?

Comment: The JSON is corrupted, there are 3 opening brackets `[` but only 1 closing `]` and one extraneous comma as second last character.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You data is invalid.It should not end with **,** before **]** bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This will work if your JSON is valid.

For Example.

[ { "locals": [
    {"name": "Mission Chinese Food", "localDescription": "A", "photograph": "img_02.jpg", "address": "171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002", "timetable": "Lunedi al Sabato 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00 Domenica 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00", "numberOfReviews": "10", "numberInCity": "2", "cityName": "New York", "ratingValue": "5" }]}]

```
if let data = JSON as? NSArray {
        for data in data {
            if let data = data as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if let data = data["locals"] as? NSArray {
                    for data in data {
                        if let data = data as? [String: AnyObject] {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this i the error that occur:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Answer (score 0):

Your Url Response data is missing functionality please check, there is no proper end of dictionary.

Below is your Json response

> {"id":0, "name": "Mission Chinese Food", "localDescription": "A ", "photograph": "img_02.jpg", "address": "171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002", "timetable": "Lunedi al Sabato 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00 Domenica 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00", "numberOfReviews": 10, "numberInCity": 2, "cityName": "New York", "ratingValue": 5 }
>   stdClass Object ( [locals] => 0 ) { "id":1, "name": "Mission Chinese Food", "localDescription": "B ", "photograph": "img_02.jpg", "address": "171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002", "timetable": "Lunedi al Sabato 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00 Domenica 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00", "numberOfReviews": 10, "numberInCity": 2, "cityName": "New York", "ratingValue": 5 }
>   stdClass Object ( [locals] => 0 ) { "id":2, "name": "Jubba the Hutt", "localDescription": "V ", "photograph": "img_02.jpg", "address": "171 E Broadway, New York, NY 10002", "timetable": "Lunedi al Sabato 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00 Domenica 08:00-12:00 e 14:00- 18:00", "numberOfReviews": 10, "numberInCity": 2, "cityName": "New York", "ratingValue": 5 }
>   stdClass Object ( [locals] => 0 ) 
>   stdClass Object ( [locals] => 0 )